# Laravel Forge - Composer Issue

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason unknown to me my server on laravel forge will no longer let me use composer i get this error:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files



[ErrorException]                                                     
Object of class Composer\IO\ConsoleIO could not be converted to int  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

This has only recently started but it means i cant actually depoly my server without an error or run tasks.

Has anybody experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be an issue regarding Forge specifically, and not part of your code, as I have just experienced it too.

My commit was a simple text content change which deployed perfectly fine yesterday evening.

Comment: Yes i believe it is, i am having the same issue on a fresh install also.

Comment: What server company are you using? My issue is with Digital Ocean

Comment: Im using digital ocean. @ben reply seemed to work for me.